# Image at the specific screen position

Tags: android, position, screen

Can I using xml layout attributes put image to the following position? Or I must calculate position on src?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gox4d.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can, for the simple example you posted I would use a vertical LinearLayout, with a FrameLayouts to 'fill' the blank space. Set the LinearLayout weightSum to 1, then set the first FrameLayout weight attribute to 0.2 (1/5), and imageview to 0.2. Also set both the frame layout and imageview layout_height values to 0px.

While this solution works, I'm sure there is a better and cleaner way out there. Hopefully someone will post it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the XML attributes.
Just use follwing attribute in your ImageView:

Android:layout_marginTop="20dip"

Android:layout_height="20dip"

Only use DIP as these are density independent Pixels
dont use PX.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AbsoluteLayout`, calculate exact coordinates based on screen size and orientation and then position the image with absolute coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use weights for different containers in a vertical linear layout.